# Meteor - Uncaught Error: No such template:

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor

I am trying to insert my "uploader" template into a modal. The modal comes up when the "uploader" template is not in there, and if another template is put in there the modal will also pop up. What am I missing? What am I doing wrong that it can't find the uploader.html? Everything is in the same folder. I spell checked. I have been trying to follow along with the Meteor Chef uploader https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3

Thank you!

modal html

```
<template name="profilePicModal">
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">


          <div class="modal-body">


              {{> uploader}}
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is the uploader.html

```
<template name="uploader">
 <div class="upload-area">
  <form id="upload">
   <p class="alert text-center">
    <span>Click or Drag a File Here to Upload</span>
    <input type="file">
  </p>
 </form>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is the uploader.js

```
Template.uploader.events({
'change input[type="file"]' ( event, template ) {
Modules.client.uploadToAmazonS3( { event: event, template: template }          );
    }
   });
```

myModal.js

```
import 'uploader.html';
import 'uploader.js';
Template.profilePicModal.events({
 'click #save': function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


});



    Modal.hide('profilePicModal');
 }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

your myModal.js file seems incomplete and malformed.
Could you fix it please.

Is your profilePicModal refers to MyModal template ?
Be sure tu use same template name you defined in the HTML file.

Comment: Hi Yann, Thank you!  I fixed that. Still does not work sadly :(